# CountdownTimer crashing app. Trying to update UI thread on tick

Tags: java, android, multithreading, countdown

I want the countdowntimer to be on a separate thread and for it to update the UI on each tick. Every time I click start the app just closes and I get the 'app has stopped' error message.

```
public class Activity_MultiplayerGame extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__multiplayer_game);
}

public void btnStart_onClick(View view){
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
                    Integer timeUntilFinished = (int) millisUntilFinished/1000;
                    countdownText.setText(timeUntilFinished);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
            countdownText.setText("Finished");
        }
    };

    timer.start();
}
}
```

I've made the assumption that creating a CountDownTimer gives it its own thread?

Comment: provide your stack trace.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)**. I wrote a sample for you

this code **increase a counter every one second** and **show and update** counter value on a **textView**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        startTimer();
    }


    int i = 0;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            textView.setText("counter:" + i);
            startTimer();
        }
    };

    public void startTimer() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

    public void cancelTimer() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cancelTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't handler bound to the UI thread? And so when it calls setText, won't this cause lag or freezes of the UI? 

I want the user to be able to input into a textbox and interact with buttons while the countdown is in effect.

Comment: it is work!  I tested it on my phone. and  also i saw before that  ExoPlayer use this code to update progressbar in videoplayer

Comment: @Jamanfi It is bound to UI thread and it's ok. You cannot manipulate UI from other than main/ui thread on andriod. You don't want to worry about freezing the UI because only time it is blocking the thread is during execution of the code inside Runnable and it's not long running code. When handler is waiting 1000ms for another countdown step, nothing is blocked or freezed.

Comment: please mark as correct answer and vote up if it  helped you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update UI from other thread than main (ui) thread on android. There are many ways to approach the problem, but I suppose you should start with [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you really need another thread. Check doInBackround and onProgressUpdate methods.

If you don't need other thread (and if this is only about the counter you dont') you can check [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class and postAtTime(Runnable, long), postDelayed(Runnable, long) methods. Or you can make subclass of Handler class  and  use combination of sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message, long) and overridden handleMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
countdownText.setText(timeUntilFinished);
```

You have passed integer to `setText(int)` method, which actually takes the string resource id rather than the integer to be displayed. You should use the method `setText(String)`.

Try this:

```
countdownText.setText(String.valueOf(timeUntilFinished));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also work it decrease counter(or increase whatever you want) and show in text view you can also stop or reset counter via click the same button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textView;
Button count;

boolean timelapseRunning = true;
int NUM_OF_COUNT=15;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    count=(Button)findViewById(R.id.count);
    runTimer();

}
public void onclick(View view){
    if (!timelapseRunning) {
       timelapseRunning=true;
    } else {
        timelapseRunning = false;

    }
    if(NUM_OF_COUNT==0){
        NUM_OF_COUNT=15;
    }
}
private void runTimer() {
           final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(""+NUM_OF_COUNT);
            if (!timelapseRunning && NUM_OF_COUNT>0) {
                NUM_OF_COUNT--;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CountDownTimer` gives out callbacks on the same thread, in which it was created. So the `runOnUiThread` in `onTick` is absolutely not required if the `CountDownTimer` constructor was called on UI thread.

Also,

```
TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
```

being called in onTick method is poor design, as `findViewById` method consumes considerable processing power.

Finally the actual problem as Nabin Bhandari pointed out is the integer value passed to `setText` method. You need to wrap it to string.
This code is enough

```
final TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countdownText.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countdownText.setText("Finished");
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```